# Fitting algebraic expression to a number [algorithm]

Tags: closed-form-expressions, algorithms

I know that it may turn out useless, but this is precisely the reason why I'm asking.

Does any one know of an existing piece of code that would find me the best approximation to a given irrational number using ordinary math symbols and known constants like e, pi etc.?

Answer (score 6):

The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Symbolic_Calculator) sounds like what you want (it's not clear from your question what form you have the number in to start with).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LLL or PSLQ to approximate your number by a linear combination over the integers of a given finite set of numbers.  Or apply them to logarithms to approximate your number as a product of powers of given numbers.  In Maple, use the IntegerRelations package.

Comment: The identify() function is easier to start with.